# swift tableview.scrollToRow() freezes ui

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a ViewController with a `tableview` inside.

I add some rows and call `tableview.reloadData()`.

I use the `tableview.scrollToRow()` call to scroll to bottom of `tableview`. and it takes quite long which freezes the UI.

Is there a way to do this in another thread or something? I even put it in `DispatchQueue` but still freezes the UI. It almost takes about 5 seconds to execute the `scrollToRow()` call.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
  let indexPath = IndexPath(row: count-1, section: 0)
  self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: Provide some context. Where is this code? What else is going on? Use the debugger and see what's going on during these 5 seconds.

Comment: there added some context around the the scrolltoRow.

Comment: Try setting `animated` to false

Comment: setting animated to false had no change

Comment: How much cells do you add? Are they loading any resources from web(ie. images)? If yes, how do you handle such loading?

Comment: Can you please elaborate you want to reload particular cell or you have to scroll to top ? explain what you want to do.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter if I am adding rows or not.  It's just calling this scrolltorow takes long even when I have not added any rows.  I am scrolling to bottom of tableview

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I have found that this is not a problem on 11.4 iOS.  Suggest update to latest IOS and try if you are having similar issue